# Text in a VStack being condensed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view similar to the below code. For some reason, my long text is being condensed, when it shouldn't be. Why is this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 8) {
                        Image(systemName: "hand.raised.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(shortText)
                            Text(longDescription)
                                .lineSpacing(4)
                                // this is being condensed
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
            }
        }
        VStack {
            // Custom Button goes here
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 70)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay well I just fixed this after posting by adding `.layoutPriority(1)` to the long text. Can anyone explain why it needed this?

Comment: I wasn't being able to reproduce it, on both iOS 14 and iOS 15 I see the full text with your code

Comment: @Tometoyou: I tried your codes there is not need for `.layoutPriority(1)` or `.lineSpacing(4)` all were good without having condensed issue! xCode: Version 12.5.1 (12E507) PS: Also do not forget using `.scaledToFit()` after `.resizable()` for Image!

Comment: Did you try it with a long piece of text? It defo truncates. And it needs lineSpacing.

Comment: Yeah! I tried with long one even!

Comment: Can you try duplicating the HStack maybe? I have a few more items within the second VStack in my real code. Didn't think that wouldve made a diff but maybe it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.layoutPriority(1)` tells the layout system that it should give priority to the desired dimensions of this view over anything with a lower priority, so it won't be condensed.

The reason your `Text` is being condensed is because it's in a `ScrollView`.

In a non-scrolling context, the layout system allows the views to expand, using the available space (i.e. the screen size) as the limit.

In a scrolling context there is no limit to the available space, so allowing views to expand to their maximum size could result in some views having an infinite size (`Color.red`, for example, will try to take as much space as possible).

This is why your `Text` view is condensed to the minimum space it supports (one line height) as opposed to the maximum size it supports.

PS. There might be a combination of modifiers that is not `layoutPriority(1)` that allows for `Text` to report it's minimum size as the required size to show all of its contents. If I have time to try and find it I will update this answer.

Comment: But what actually causes it to condense?

Comment: @Tometoyou added more details to my answer

Comment: Okay, it doesn't actually condense to one line, but three lines high. I guess that makes sense though